# Big O analysis for this for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, big-o, time-complexity, code-analysis

```
 sum = 0;
 for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {    //#1
   for (j = 1; j <= i * i; j++) {     //#2
      if (j % i == 0) {    //#3 
          for (k = 1; k <= j; k++) {   //#4
             sum++;
         }
     }
  }
```

}

The above got me confusing

```
Suppose #1 runs for N times
    #2 runs for N^2 times
    #3 runs for  N/c since for N inputs N/c could be true conditions
    #4 runs for  N times
```

Therefore roughly I could be looking at O(N^5) . I am not sure. Please help clarify.

**EDIT** I was wondering the runtime at the `if(j%i==0)`. Since it takes `N^2` inputs from its parent loop it could be doing `(N^2)/c` executions instead of `N/c`

Comment: looks O(N^5) to me as well. but you shouldnt really consider #3 (the if itself, not the loop it contains) since it adds a 0.5 multiplier, which you shouldnt take into account for big-O stuff.
so you get N times for #1, times N^2 for #2 times N^2 for #4 (multiplied by 0.5 which is ignored)

Comment: I see..So how come #4 has N^2 iterations according to your analysis?

Comment: I think `i` would be a factor of `j` much less often than half the time.

Comment: `(j%i==0)` is not checking whether numbers are even...

Comment: Oh yea, sorry I forgot about that. I thing putting `N/c` should be right thing to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say its O(N^4) as its the same as.

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)        //#1 O(n ...
   for (int j = i; j <= i * i; j+=i) //#2 ... * n ...
     for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++)    //#4 ... * n^2) as j ~= i^2
         sum++;
```

or

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int n = 9000;
    System.out.println((double) f(n * 10) / f(n));
}

private static long f(long n) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++)   //#1
        for (long j = 1; j <= i; j++) //#2
            sum += i * j; // # 4
    return sum;
}
```

prints

```
9996.667534360826
```

which is pretty close to 10^4

Comment: I see. So are you saying that #4 for loop executes N times instead of N^2?

Comment: +1 for the right answer.  Although it can be proved mathematically rather than empirically (although that can be left as an exercise for the OP)...

Comment: I think the reduce in the first sample code make it relatively obvious.

Comment: +1, I am just performing so benchmarking as well and it indeed is `O(N^4)`

Answer (score 1):

@PeterLawrey did the math, here are benchmarks plotted on chart ([my data set](https://gist.github.com/2342986) - `n` vs. execution time in microseconds).

Basically I run the code in question several times with different `n` input (X-axis). Then I divided average execution time by `n^5`, `n^4` and `n^3` functions and plotted that:

[image]

[<sup>Full size image</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBoAa.png)

Note that this is a logarithmic scale and that all functions were scaled to more-or-less be in the same range.

Guess what, avergae execution time `t(n)` divided by `n^5` keeps getting decreasing, while `t(n)/n^3` keeps growing. Only `t(n)/n^4` is stabilizes when approaching infinity which proves that the **average execution time is in fact `O(n^4)`**.

Comment: Hmm, this approach might work for simple examples like the OP's.  But it shouldn't be recommended as a general approach; in a more complex example, the n^4 term may dominate until, say, n=1000000, and then a n^5 term might take over.  The only way to be sure is to do the maths.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: +1, actually I forgot to add it to my answer. As I said Peter did the math (transformation of an algorithm), this is just an empiric "prove". You are right, it won't work in some cases, but this one is simple enough - and looks cool IMHO ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer, using Sigma notation, would be like the following:

[image]