# Big O Theory- triple nested loop

Tags: big-o, nested-loops

If I have a function of:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   for(j=0;j<i*i;j++)
      for(k=0;k<j;k++)
         System.out.println(k);
```

Would the `big O` of this function be `n^5` from having:
`n*((n-1)^2)*((n-1)^2)-1`?

Comment: hint: it's O(n^3) if you iterate through all the k values

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big O analysis for this for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071692/big-o-analysis-for-this-for-loop)

Answer (score 3):

Your function is `O(1)` because it returns the first `k`, the loop ends at first iteration. Assuming it don't return immediately, it is n^5 as you thought.

​​
For each i the second loop is looping `i^2` times, and the third loop is going `j` times. 
So for each `i` it is looping `i^4` times. So the total is `Sum(i^4) (1..n)` which is `O(n^5)`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited and fixed. So it is n^5 based on what I wrote, correct?

Comment: @user3242955 Yeah it is.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, using Sigma Notation, you can infer the order of growth through the following:

[image]