# Big O Remainder/Modulus Loops

Tags: for-loop, big-o, modulo

I am working out a function:

```
total = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
  for (j = 0; j < i*i; j++){
     if (j % i == 0){
        for (k=0; k <  j; k++){
          total++;
```

I the Big O number for this N^4 or N^5 when you break it down. I am not sure how to handle the % sign and the run time of that inner loop.

Comment: Could you fix the indentation? It's not entirely clear when the inner loop runs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big O analysis for this for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071692/big-o-analysis-for-this-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

A roughly equivalent code would be

```
total=0;
for (i=1; i<=N; i++)
    for(j=1; j <= i*i; j+= i)
        for (k=1; k <= j; k++)
            total++;
```

by restricting `j` to those values that are actually divisible by `i`. Shifting the range of each variable by one avoids the issue of having `i = 0`.

Rewriting again gives

```
total=0;
for (i=1; i<=N; i++)
    for(j=1; j <= i; j+= 1)
        for (k=1; k <= j*j; k++)
            total++;
```

The `j` loop iterates the same number of times, but instead ranging over the square numbers directly, we simply iterate over the simple integers and shift the multiplication into the `k` loop. From this, it should be a little easier to prove that `total` is increment O(N^4) times: the inner `k` loop runs O(N^2) times, and itself iterates over O(N^2) values.