# Time complexity analysis with modulus

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

```
 sum = 0;
 for(i=1;i<2*n;i++)
    for(j=1;j<i*i;j++)
      for(k=1;k<j;k++)
        if (j % i == 1)
          sum++;
```

I need to calculate the time complexity of this code in terms of big O notation. I understand how to analyze time complexity on a very basic level. My problem is the condition in the final 
inner loop. How do I integrate it in my analysis?

Comment: What time of analysis are you performing? If you are doing a worst-case analysis, assume the if statement is true. If it is coupled with an else statement, assume whichever is more complex.

Comment: Yes it is worst time. Thanks

Comment: The answer is O(N^4). Could you explain the way to the answer?

Comment: Typically here at SO we help with specific problems. If you can work through the problem a bit, show what you think you have so far and highlight what you don't understand, we can help answer specific questions. However, if you don't understand complexity analysis really you would be better served speaking with someone (assuming this is for a class).

Comment: I understand. It's not for a class tho. I am trying to learn it by myself

Comment: Where did you get the answer from? I'm getting O(N^5) so far?

Comment: It's a worksheet I found online. There are no explanations to the answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big O analysis for this for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071692/big-o-analysis-for-this-for-loop)

Answer (score 5):

```
 sum = 0;
 for(i=1;i<2*n;i++)
    for(j=1;j<i*i;j++)
      for(k=1;k<j;k++)
        if (j % i == 1)
          sum++;
```

So:

- `i` goes from `1` to `2n`, hence this is `O(n)`.
- `j` goes from `1` to `i^2`, hence this is `O(n^2)`.
- `k` takes on the same values as `j`, hence it is `O(n^2)`.

Everything else is constant time. So the final complexity is `O(n^5)`.

Comment: The entire unoptimized algorithm is O(n^5), but `sum++` is only called O(n^4) times as explained by huseyin's answer, so it depends on what you're measuring.

Answer (score 4):

From "sum++"'s eyes:

```
sum = 0;
 for(i=1;i<2*n;i++)      //  O(n)
    for(j=1;j<i*i;j++)   //  O(n) * O(n*n)
      for(k=1;k<j;k++)   //  O(n) * O(n*n) * O(n*n)
        if (j % i == 1)  //  O(n) * O(n*n) * O(n*n) * O(1) 
          sum++;         //  O(n) * O(n*n) * O(n*n) * O(1) * O(1) = O(n^5)
```

Its equivalent to

```
sum = 0;
 for(i=1;i<2*n;i++)        //O(n)
    for(j=1;j<i*i;j+=i)    //O(n)*O(n)  because increment step is i
      for(k=1;k<j;k++)     //O(n)*O(n)*O(n*n) becuase from 1 to order of n*n step 1
          sum++;           // O(n^4)
```

Absence of branching should not change complexity but performance, sum++ gets called O(n^4) times.

Of course endless mathematical optimizations can make all these O(1) so it is O(n^5) if there is not just an increment(plus an "else" and even more).

Heavily optimized:

```
sum = 0;
 for(i=1;i<2*n;i++)        //O(n)
    for(j=1;j<i*i;j+=i)    //O(n)*O(n)  because increment step is i
          sum+=(j*(j+1)/2);           // O(n^3)
```

Continues until  O(1)  as sum of sum of sum approach.

Comment: I got the top part perfectly. What did you do to optimize it? (The answer is O(n^4))

Comment: Ah curses, I failed to consider how the optimization might knock of an `n`.  Well done!

Comment: if(j%1==1) is satisfied for only 1,1+i,1+2*i,... so the rest of it is not incrementing the sum. Step should be i insted of 1. Also sum from k=1 to j step 1 is equal to k*(k+1)/2 so you can knock out another n :) till you reach O(1) :)

Comment: How will this look like if it was optimized further? Also I understand time complexity, but how do you go about with making these optimizations?

Comment: For this example, its mostly math optimizations. Just melding into a single equaiton. Im not that good at math. But im sure wolframalpha site can do that automatically if you could write a parsable script for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can tackle the analysis of your algorithm, to formally the asymptotic order of growth, like the following:

[image]

The equation above tells the number of times the `if` statement will be executed.